# Java singleton inner class

Tags: java, singleton, inner-classes

I know the concept of singleton in Java.
I'm having problems with creating singleton as inner class in Java. Problem occurs at holder's

```
public class NormalClass {
    private class Singleton {
        private static Singleton instance = null;

        private Singleton() {
        }

        private static class SingletonHolder {
            private static Singleton sessionData = new Singleton();
        }

        public static Singleton getInstance() {
            return NormalClass.Singleton.SingletonHolder.sessionData;
        }
    }

    public void method1() {
        Singleton.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Error is at new Singleton() constructor call. How to proper call private constructor of Singleton as inner class?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it should be a real singleton, make your singleton class static. Then you will be able to call the constructor.

The reason why your constructor call does not work is explained in the [Java nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) tutorial. Basically, the inner class requires an instance of the outer class before it can be constructed:

```
private static Singleton sessionData = new NormalClass().new Singleton();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare static classes within a non-static class. Make the `Singleton` class static and everything should compile just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the inner class is not static inner class,

```
public class NormalClass {
  private static class Singleton {
      private static Singleton instance = null;

      private Singleton() {
      }

      private static class SingletonHolder {
          private static Singleton sessionData = new Singleton();
      }

      public static Singleton getInstance() {
          return NormalClass.Singleton.SingletonHolder.sessionData;
      }
  }

  public void method1() {
      Singleton.getInstance();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize on Demand.... Joshua Bloch..

I think if your inner class is static, your holder class should also be static.

```
private static class SingletonHolder {
    static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
}
```

Or Why not like this? why an inner holder class at all ?

```
public class NormalClass{
  private static class InnerClass{
    private static InnerClass instance = null;
    private InnerClass(){}
    public static InnerClass getInstance() {
  if(null==NormalClass.InnerClass.instance){
    NormalClass.InnerClass.instance = new InnerClass(); 
  }
  return NormalClass.InnerClass.instance;
}
  }

  public void test(){
    InnerClass.getInstance();
  }
}
```